# Extra button displayed when iterating rails objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into a problem where there is an extra up and down button displaying on the page. How can I fix this?
[image]
My View is the following:

```
<% @group.posts.each do |p| %>

<tr>
  <td>
    <%= p.body %>
  </td>

  <td>
    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon-arrow-up">Up</span>
      </button>
      <%= p.votes %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon-arrow-down">Down</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </td>

</tr>

<% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
def show
  @group = Group.find_by_name(params[:name])
  @post = @group.posts.new
end
```

Comment: is that all the code the view contains?

Comment: Check the DB, is there an extra record?

Answer (score 3):

By calling

```
@group.posts.new
```

you are adding an empty post to the group, which you see the buttons rendered for.

You can either assign all the posts before to another variable in your controller and use that for rendering all posts

```
@posts = @group.posts.to_a
```

or by doing the `@post` initialization a bit different,

```
@post = Post.new(group: @group)
```

Alternatively, you could filter the posts you are rendering the buttons for:

```
@group.posts.select(&:persisted?).each do |p|
```

Comment: Thats a possible solution - but it could just as well be due to a record in the db with no body attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do `@post = @group.posts.new` in the controller. It adds empty Post object.

You can just reload it before iterating `reload` => `@group.posts.reload.each do |p|`